# R Markdown Plot Image Quality Loss When Using Foundation 4 CSS

Tags: css, r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

So I've been using R markdown to make some reports and I decided to spruce it up a bit by using the Foundation 4 CSS framework with it.

I embedded the minimized Foundation css in the file and then applied the styles to the R markdown code and it works fine but the quality of the image that is coming out is much lower than what was coming out via just R markdown.

Inside the R code I have:

```
cat('<div class = "Row">')
cat('<div class = "Foundationy grid columns">')
Bunch of R plot code here
cat('</div>')
etc...
```

I guess Foundation is changing the image quality somehow?

Any ideas on what I can change in the CSS to fix this?

Comment: I switched to Toast which is a much more lightweight CSS framework and there was no problem with the image quality... Curious what the issue is in Foundation though.

Comment: Does it matter if you use embedded images versus external images?

Comment: R Markdown embeds the images in the page, but when I switched to Toast it didn't mess with the image formatting anymore.  I guess there is something in Foundation that messes with the embedded image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Toast which is a much more lightweight CSS framework and the problem disappeared.

I'm assuming Foundation has some style that effects images.  I didn't locate the style but switching frameworks was a decent workaround.